# C# - Linq-To-SQL - Issue with queries

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am thoroughly frustrated right now.  I am having an issue with LINQ-To-SQL.  About 80% of the time, it works great and I love it.  The other 20% of the time, the query that L2S creates returns the correct data, but when actually running it from code, it doesn't return anything.  I am about to pull my hair out.  I am hoping somebody can see a problem or has heard of this before.  Google searching isn't returning much of anything.

Here is the linq query...

```
var query = from e in DataLayerGlobals.GetInstance().db.MILLERTIMECARDs
        where e.deleted_by == -1
        && e.LNAME == lastName
        && e.FNAME == firstName
        && e.TIMECARDDATE == startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        group e by e.LNAME into g
        select new EmployeeHours
        {
            ContractHours = g.Sum(e => e.HRSCONTRACT),
            MillerHours = g.Sum(e => e.HRSSHOWRAIN + e.HRSOTHER),
            TravelHours = g.Sum(e => e.HRSTRAVEL)
        };
```

This is the generated query....

```
 SELECT SUM([t0].[HRSCONTRACT]) AS [ContractHours], 
        SUM([t0].[HRSSHOWRAIN] + [t0].[HRSOTHER]) AS [MillerHours], 
        SUM([t0].[HRSTRAVEL]) AS [TravelHours]
 FROM [dbo].[MILLERTIMECARD] AS [t0]
 WHERE ([t0].[deleted_by] = @p0) 
    AND ([t0].[LNAME] = @p1) 
    AND ([t0].[FNAME] = @p2) 
    AND ([t0].[TIMECARDDATE] = @p3)
 GROUP BY [t0].[LNAME]
```

Now when I plug in the EXACT same values that the linq query is using into the generated query, I get the correct data.  When I let the code run, I get nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is TIMECARDDATE? Date, datetime, datetime2, smalldatetime, datetimeoffset or character?

Any chance local date/time settings are messing up the date comparison of `startDate.ToString(...)`? Since you're sending @p3 as a *string*, `01/02/2009` may mean Feb 1st *or* January 2nd, depending on the date/time setting on the server.

Comment: TIMECARDDATE is a string.  Yes, yes, I know.  I inherited this database, and changing it is not an option.  

This maybe the issue.  It works when the date is 10/19/2009, but doesn't work when the date is 10/5/2009.  Would this be a SQL Server issue or LINQ issue?

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo Your comment about the failure on 10/5/2009 and the fact that the db dates are just strings makes me think your format string should be "MM/d/yyyy" instead so that you get "10/5/2009" and not "10/05/2009" as your current code would.

Comment: Dude...you are so awesome.  That was it.  I ended up using "M/d/yyyy" so the months wouldn't have a leading 0 which seemed to also cause the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is telling me that you need to be pulling out `DataLayerGlobals.GetInstance().db.MILLERTIMECARDs` into an `IQueryable` variable and executing your Linq query against that, although there really should be no difference at all (other than maybe better readability).

You can check the results of the `IQueryable` variable first, before running the Linq query against it.

To extend this concept a bit further, you can create a series of IQueryable variables that each store the results of a Linq query using each individual condition in the original query.  In this way, you should be able to isolate the condition that is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also have a look at the LNAME & FNAME data types. If they're NCHAR/NVARCHAR you may need to Trim the records, e.g.

```
var query = from e in DataLayerGlobals.GetInstance().db.MILLERTIMECARDs
    where e.deleted_by == -1
    && e.LNAME.Trim() == lastName
    && e.FNAME.Trim() == firstName
    && e.TIMECARDDATE == startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    group e by e.LNAME into g
    select new EmployeeHours
    {
        ContractHours = g.Sum(e => e.HRSCONTRACT),
        MillerHours = g.Sum(e => e.HRSSHOWRAIN + e.HRSOTHER),
        TravelHours = g.Sum(e => e.HRSTRAVEL)
    };
```